# laravel auth model sub account user login

Tags: laravel, authentication, account

How do I enter subaccounts with Laravel?
**Example**: Add sub account id and master account id to the session value `$ _SESSION = array ("userid" => "1", "subaccountid" => "51");`

Answer (score 0):

You can select userid from User table and except Auth:user()->id

```
User::whereNotIn('userid', Auth:user()->id)->get();
```